# Can ELMAH both log to SQL and generate an Email?

Tags: elmah

I had ELMAH 1.111517.2009 logging to a SQL Server Express DB just fine.  I added email support via the errorMail tag and friends.  It sends email now but it also no longer puts the error info in the SQL DB?  Is there a configuration trick I'm missing or is this just how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.  In granting EXECUTE privilege to Elmah's three sprocs, I missed the ELMAH_LogError sproc.  It's doing both logging to SQL and emailing now.

Comment: P.S. If anybody else wants to submit a similar answer I'd gladly mark it as the answer.  I hate getting credit for answering my own stupid questions.

Comment: Nothing wrong with you posting a question and instead of disappearing, happy with you own answer, you posted it here.